# Delphi: Method 'Create' hides virtual method of base - but it's right there

Tags: delphi, overloading

Consider the hypothetical object hierarchy, starting with:

```
TFruit = class(TObject)
public
    constructor Create(Color: TColor); virtual;
end;
```

and its descendant:

```
TApple = class(TFruit)
public
    constructor Create(); overload; virtual;
    constructor Create(Color: TColor); overload; override; //deprecated. Calls other constructor - maintaining the virtual constructor chain
end;
```

The idea here is that I've **overridden** the **virtual** constructor of the base class, with an **overload** that also happens to be virtual.

Delphi complains:

> Method 'Create' hides virtual method of base type 'TFruit'

Except it doesn't hide it - it's right there!

- I ***overrode*** the virtual method in the ancestor, and
- I ***overloaded*** it with another version

What's the deal?

Comment: I get "Method 'Create' hides virtual method of base type 'TFruit'"; are you really getting "base type 'TApple'"?

Comment: @RBA Not exactly, the warning is incorrect in this case, although you can use `reintroduce;` to avoid it.

Comment: This is specific to Delphi 5?

Comment: @EMBarbosa No, but when using an older version, you might wonder if such a thing _is_ specific to that version. OP is just being informative.

Comment: @NGLN Yup. So I think it doesn't need delphi-5 tag?

Comment: @EMBarbosa i *am* in Delphi 5. i don't know if newer versions of the language solve the problem by doing something completely different (e.g. linq closure delegate modads, with multiple interface inheritance and attributes). i include `delphi-5` so that the solution should be a fix in the language. And i don't know what pieces of information are relevant when i ask a question. Some people get grumpy when skip additional information.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Two solutions:

```
type
  TFruit = class(TObject)
  public
    constructor Create(Color: TColor); virtual;
  end;

  TApple = class(TFruit)
  public
    constructor Create(); reintroduce; overload;
    constructor Create(Color: TColor); overload; override;
  end;
```

Or:

```
type
  TFruit = class(TObject)
  public
    constructor Create; overload; virtual; abstract;
    constructor Create(Color: TColor); overload; virtual;
  end;

  TApple = class(TFruit)
  public
    constructor Create(); override;
    constructor Create(Color: TColor); override; 
  end;
```

Comment: +1. I couldn't find a combination of `overload`, `virtual`, and/or `override` that made XE2's compiler happy. :)

Comment: @WarrenP That smell comes from other uses of `reintroduce` which often break inheritance.

Comment: @NGLN In my case the compiler is fighting me when i'm trying to maintain inheritance. i could hide the ancestors and be done with it, but that would break polymorphic constructors.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks Polymorphic constructors are another code smell?

Comment: @WarrenP, `TComponent.Create` is a polymorphic constructor and it's central to the way Delphi works. I think it's beautiful, I don't smell anything.

Comment: I'm willing to accept the limited use within the VCL (TComponent.Create), but when application codebases have used extensive polymorphic constructors, it has seemed like a code-smell to me.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a "which came first" sort of issue. (It appears NGLN found a solution.)

There's another solution, also. You can use a default parameter:

```
interface

type
  TFruit=class(TObject)
  public
    constructor Create(Color: TColor); virtual;
  end;

  TApple=class(TFruit)
  public
    constructor Create(Color: TColor = clRed); override;
  end;

implementation

{ TFruit }

constructor TFruit.Create(Color: TColor);
begin
  inherited Create;
end;

{ TApple }

constructor TApple.Create(Color: TColor);
begin
  inherited;
end;

// Test code
var
  AppleOne, AppleTwo: TApple;
begin
  AppleOne := TApple.Create;
  AppleTwo := TApple.Create(clGreen);
end;
```

Comment: +1 For creativity. But reintroduce isn't needed, and I would use `clDefault`. ;)

Comment: Thanks. :) You're right. I think that's a remnant of one of the earlier trials, and the compiler didn't complain, so I didn't catch it. And I've never seen a `clDefault` colored apple. ;)

Comment: I didn't mention it for coloring the apple, but to stick to the question's purpose of the added parameterless constructor in TApple. Clearly OP thinks there are apples without any color. ;) Besides, what color is clDefault anyway? It is the default color of an apple, isn't it? (Ok, it's implemented as black, but that's just because TColor simply requires some integer value).

Comment: ;) I've never seen anything colored `clDefault` that I'd select as an apple I'd want to eat. <g> It just seemed to me that, if you're creating a fruit called `Apple`, it should default to a typical color value for an apple (red, green, yellow or gold, etc.). :) I'd prefer not to see apples sit around until they turn black, but that may just be my own bias. <g>

Comment: Yeah, well, this is all a bit rhetoric, and the apple sample isn't making it a better case for me. But surely OP isn't designing fruit inheritance. The general point I am making is to make use of `clDefault` when speaking of _a default color_. Certainly a default parameter is somewhat meant to be _default_. ;) I make use of `clDefault` quite often: e.g. when setting a color property to `clDefault`, the color switches back to _a default state_ and could turn into any other color bút `clDefault` depending on other properties of the component. I'll stop now... ;)

Comment: :) My last one: I specifically chose `clRed` as the default *because* the asker used `TApple` and `TFruit`, since it fit. In other circumstances, I'd probably use `clDefault`, unless there was an obviously better value to default to (such as `clMoneyGreen` for a `TUSPaperCurrency` class color property, or `clSkyBlue` for a `TSky` color). Now *I'll* stop. :)